# What does fast-fail mode do?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019

According to the help text, the Microsoft C++ compiler, Visual Studio 2019, has this option:

```
/fastfail[-] enable fast-fail mode
```

What does this mode do? I was hoping it might cause the compiler to stop after one error message instead of spanning multiple screenfuls, but sadly no, and a Google search doesn't shed any light on it.

Comment: Admittedly, only a 'guess', but may it enable/disable use of [the `__fastfail` intrinsic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/fastfail?view=msvc-160)?

Comment: I tried a very simple program with `__fastfail(3);` in it and it compiled and ran with the same result, with or without `/fastfail` or `/fastfail-`.

Comment: Or maybe it's a linker thing: https://codereview.chromium.org/1816333002 ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/cpp-docs/issues/1079.

> **tamlin-mike**: So are you ever going to document this option?

> **corob-msft**: We'll get to it eventually. For the curious, when the `/FASTFAIL` option is set, the linker captures exception info **on linker faults,** then calls `RaiseFailFastException` to **create a dump file.** It's useful for debugging linker issues, so you might get asked to use it when generating a repro for Developer Community. In normal linker use, you don't need this option. **It doesn't affect generated images in any way.**